# add datatype attribute to property runtime dependent on another property mvc5

Tags: types, attributes, runtime, asp.net-mvc-5

In my model I want to do something like that

```
public string Something { get; set; }

[DataType(Something.Contains("whatever") ? "whatever" : "notwhatever")]
public double Price{ get; set; }
```

this way it doesnt work.
possible at all? how?

Comment: No that is not possible. For a start, attributes are metadata and must be known at compile time (i.e. must be constants, which property `Something` is not). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am using js wrapper library (kendo) which renders editor templates based on dataType attribute of the property.. and for numeric box i want different steps and decimals depending on that 'something', read its possible for validation attributes, unfortunately not for datatype (